# RESTful URL with Backbone help needed with URL redirection

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

This is a small peice of code in my index.html :

```
<a href="#driver.html"><button type="button"
class="btn btn-default btn-large active style="border-right-color: white">Drivers</button></a>
```

my router.js
i have included the view

```
 routes: {
   '': 'defaultAction',
   'drivers':'driver'

}

driver:function(){
console.log("Drivers");
var addview = new AddDriverView({el: $("#content")});
```

//I want to load the view in my content so #content
    addview.render();

);}

The output in the console is Drivers.
Now i want the driver function to load a view. how ?

**Update** My view i have given as

```
        var AddDriverView = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: '#addDriver',  // addDriver is the id of the form of the view i have created as view.adddriver.htm(it comtains only the form and nothing else.)

                events: {
                    'submit': 'submit'
                },
                ***render: function() {
                    $(this.el).html();    
                },***

                submit: function(e) {
// some code
}
});
```

is the render function correct ?? all i am trying is to render the form ...

@kunerd

Comment: missing one " behind last class (active)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many resources online on how to instantiate a Backbone view.

Please read this: [What is a view?](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-view/)

And then look at the corresponding [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas/C9wew/4/)

EDIT: As I can see so far, your problem is that you doesn't call your views `render()` method anywhere. You could call it after initialization in your router, or you could call it in the views `initialize` method.

in controller:

```
AppRouter = Backbone.Route.extend({
  ...
  driver:function(){
    console.log("Drivers");
    var addview = new AddDriverView({el: $("#content")});
    addView.render();
  }
  ...
});
```

or in view:

```
AddDriverView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    this.render();
  }
});
```

EDIT: explanation of routers driver function:
The `new AddDriverView({el: $("#content")});` creates a new instance of your AddDriverView class. The `el` property bind this view to the existing DOM element with id `content`. If you doesn't specify one Backbone will always create a DIV element.
The method call `addView.render()` tells your newly created view to render its content into the DOM, and there into the element with the id `content`.
For further details please take a Look at [Backbone's Documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el).

Also you need to user your `#addDriver` content as template in your view.

```
render: function(){
  var template = _.template( $("#search_template").html(),{});
  this.$el.html( template );
}
```

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vwZXN/2/) should help you.
Here some more informations about [underscore templates](http://underscorejs.org/#template), because it is used above.

But there are many ways of creating Views and how to use the router. For further information look at this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398319/layout-and-view-management).

Comment: var addview = new AddDriverView({ el:$("#content")});
addview.render();
can you please explain what this two lines in my router will do ??
whenever i run the project, browser shows error only in the first line..
can you please explain the first line clearly..
maybe i am doing some minor mistake

Comment: is this correct  ????    i am creating a addview object of the view type AddDriverView.. once browser see AddDriverView, it will go to the view and execute it and come back and sees that this has to be put in the id "content"...
and when it see addview.render it delivers the output..

Comment: Edited my post to answer your additional questions.